# KafkaConsumer does not read all records from topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I want to test a kafka example, the producer:

```scala
object ProducerApp extends App {

  val topic = "topicTest"
  val  props = new Properties()
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "consumer")
  props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
  props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
  val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
  for(i <- 0 to 125000)
  {    
    val record = new ProducerRecord(topic, "key "+i,new PMessage())    
    producer.send(record)       
  }
}
```

The consumer:

```scala
object ConsumerApp extends App {
  val topic = "topicTest"  
  val properties = new Properties
  properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")
  properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "consumer")  
  properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false")  
  properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
  properties.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
  properties.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
  val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](properties)  
  consumer.subscribe(scala.List(topic).asJava)    
  while (true) {
    consumer.seekToBeginning(consumer.assignment())
    val records:ConsumerRecords[String,String] = consumer.poll(20000)
    println("records size "+records.count())    
  }  
}
```

The topic "topicTest" is created with 1 partition.

The expected result is:

```
...
records size 125000
records size 125000
records size 125000
records size 125000
...
```

but the obtained result is:

```
...
records size 778
records size 778
records size 778
records size 778
...
```

The consumer does not read all the records from the topic. I want to understand the reason. However, if the number of records is smaller (20 for example), it works fine and the consumer reads all the records. Is the size of the topic limited?
Is there a modification in the configuration of Kafka to allow the process of a big number of records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `max.poll.records` consumer parameters which has 500 as default with Kafka 1.0.0 so you can't have the result you want with 125000.
For this reason it works with 20 but it's strange the result 778 you have.

Comment: Thank you, I think that the reason is the log cleaner process. The default cleanup policy is "delete". I want to keep all the records in the topic all the time (without deleting any record). What's the right way : make "log.cleaner.enable=false" or "log.cleanup.policy=compact"?

Comment: You need just log.cleaner.enable=false. It's not importat what you set for log.cleanup.policy because you are just disabling the cleaner to run. When you set it to true then it makes sense to specify the policy as delete or compact if you want messages being deleted or topic being compacted.